# How to limit the size of the AdvancedDataGrid to its rows with variable row heights

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, advanceddatagrid

I tried to limit the size of the AdvancedDataGrid to its rows. Currently I am using variableRowHeight to true and at the run time setting the itemRenderer's height.

Hence every row has different height. But I found that the logic behind the calculation of Grid's height is plain and simple - measure the height of the first row, then multiply it with the number of rows. *Please correct me if I am wrong here*

I did some POC on the issue and found that during the **calculateRowHeight** event -> it calculates the individual row height but somewhere down the line it is only multiplying the rowCount with the first row's height. Instead it should calculate every row and should sum up the height.

Please suggest a way to overcome this.

PS: I tried below options:
1. rowCount = arrayCollection.length
2. dataGrid.height = dataGrid.measureHeightOfItems(0, arrayCollection.length)+ dataGrid.headerHeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can be used in the measure overriden method of the extended AdvancedDataGrid:

```
override protected function measure():void
{
    super.measure();
    if(this.dataProvider != null && this.dataProvider.length > 0)
    {
        this.measuredHeight = this.measureHeightOfItems(0, dataProvider.length);
    }
}
```

This will calculate the height of all the rows and will set the datagrid height accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing you can do is specify the height of the datagrid and the height of each row within it.  The whole variable height thing is not consistent.

Comment: That is not an option, as per the requirement I can not set the fixed row height, it has to be different. Some of the rows contains some graphics while some contains only some text.

Answer (score 0):

If you found that the problem is inside this specific method, maybe you can try to extend the AdvancedDataGrid and override the calculateRowHeight method to do this sum.

```
public class MyAdvancedDatagrid extends AdvancedDataGrid {

    override protected function calculateRowHeight(data:Object, hh:Number, skipVisible:Boolean = false):Number {
     //Your code here
    }

}
```

Comment: Here it calculates the individual row height, but here I can not set the datagrid height. and moreover this overriden method is called before the measure method inside the AdvancedDataGrid.

Comment: On further investigation I found that if the dataGrid height is set to something less, then only the visible rows are being calculated.

Answer (score 0):

The advanced data grid employs the same recycling methodolog of all list in flex.  It only creates item renderers for the visual data on the screen. Each and every row found to be non-visible does not have an item renderer created for it, thus the item renderer cannot measure and report a height ot the grid, thus you cannot get the exact height of the grid with variable row height set to true and more data than fits on the screen.

If you want to measure exactly how much height the grid would need, create an item renderer for each row in your data provider, validate and measure it.

Comment: "item renderer for each row" As per my knowledge the item renderer are set on the columns. Could you please let me know on which event should I measure the height of the item renderer. And how to sum up the height of all item renderers?